# Why am I getting a Typescript type error for a Date field?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following Typescript function:

```
  isAttendanceDuplicate(date: Date, attendances: Attendance[]): boolean {
    const dateValues = new Array<number>();
    attendances.filter(as => as.isHidden === false).forEach(a => {
      const attendanceDate = new Date(a.date.getFullYear(), a.date.getMonth(), a.date.getDate());
      dateValues.push(attendanceDate.valueOf())
    });
    const matchingDateVales = dateValues.filter(d => d === date.valueOf());

    return matchingDateVales.length > 0;
  }
```

And this is the definition for an attendance:

```
export class Attendance {
  calendarItemId: string;
  calendarItemTypeId: number;
  hasNoDueEvent: boolean;
  clientId: string;
  dueEventId: string;
  resultEventId: string;
  calendarItemName: string;
  type: number;
  status: number;
  date: Date;
  isHidden: boolean;
  statusName: string;
  hasOpenAlert: boolean;
}
```

As you can see in that class date is a Date.

When attempting to create a new Date (attendanceDate) I get the following error:

"TypeError: a.date.getFullYear is not a function." Why?

Comment: Ah... let's just try the usual programmer's debugging method of `console.log` and logging that sucker.

Comment: You get that error at *runtime*, so your problem is there.  Presumably the actual value of `date` is not a `Date`, and whoever passed in `attendances` didn’t do what they were supposed to.  Where is that code?

Comment: or a.date is not filled

Comment: you need to check if a.date is not null or undefined

Comment: I added the console.log statement you see above. I got this for the first date in attendances: date 2025-02-24T08:00:00. And then the error.

Comment: also...your code should not fail if you are passed unexpected or bad values. It can throw an exception for the user, or process what it can and return a more informative value than boolean pass/fail.

Comment: As  jcalz said, please, show us the code where `attendances` is istanciated, before being passed at  `isAttendanceDuplicate` function.